# msgBox is not showing up on successful result

Tags: excel, msgbox, vba

I have the below set up to copy a list and paste to sheet(data). I want it to display a message when it is successful, telling me which row did it started the paste at. However, the errmsg shows instead.

Thanks in advance

```
    Dim current As String
   current = ActiveCell.Index
    MsgBox current & "pasted there"

    Exit Sub
errmsg:
    MsgBox "failed to copy."
End Sub
```

full code

```
Sub move()
    Range("A3:B3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Range("K3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Range("F3:I3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    Range("F3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    Range("A3:G3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy

    On Error GoTo errmsg
    Sheets("data").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Dim current As String
   current = ActiveCell.Index
    MsgBox current & "pasted there"

    Exit Sub
errmsg:
    MsgBox "failed to copy."
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no `Index property or method` for range objects. That might be causing the error as what @Pillgram mentioned in his post. You can try `ActiveCell.Row` instead to get the row where you pasted the values.

Comment: I used .Row instead of .address but both worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO:) One way to try to debug this would be to remove/comment-out the "On Error GoTo", then run the code. That should show you which line is generating the error. 
That said, I suspect you want `current = ActiveCell.Index` to be `current = ActiveCell.Address`.

Comment: I used .Row (suggested by @L42)instead of .address but both worked. Thank you